# Butter Knife and Material Design Library usage

Tags: android, user-interface, butterknife

I am using Butter Knife in my project along with the Material Design Libraries for the UI.

When attempting to create buttons using the Material Design Library i get a 'Class Cast Exception' because of the usage of Butter Knife.

Is there a way to fix this?

MainActivity.Java

```
@Bind(R.id.switch1) Switch switch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

XML Switch Layout

```
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Errors

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for com.example.MainActivty

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:com.gc.materialdesign.views.Switch cannot be cast to android.widget.Switch
```

Comment: Put your code in your question.

Comment: Are you sure that you imported the correct `Switch` in your MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the wrong `Switch` - instead of importing `android.widget.Switch`, you need to import `com.gc.materialdesign.views.Switch` and use that class when defining your `switch` variable.

Comment: I literally just figured it out, i thought the library was already imported! Stupid me. Thank you for for your answer i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
import android.widget.Switch;
```

and replace it with

```
import com.gc.materialdesign.views.Switch;
```

You've simply chosen to import the wrong `Switch` class.